# Unable to set User Selected Sound to Push Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Hi I'm working on Push Notification in my app.
In that I'm able to get Notification successfully.
I'm trying to set user selected sound to Push notification.
For that I'm storing user selected sound file path in preferences

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notif_icon));
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    mBuilder.setTicker("Message from " +context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(CommonUtilities.sp.getString("PUSHNOTIFICATIONTONE", "Null"));
    Log.d("Path: ", uri.toString());
    mBuilder.setSound(uri);
```

I'm getting exact path in Log as I selected before

```
09-19 16:14:45.511: D/Path:(17832): content://com.estrongs.files/mnt/sdcard/Ringtones/bbm_tone.wav
```

Can Any one tell me, where I'm getting wrong??

Comment: check have you  set the permissions in manifest ?

Comment: which permission you talking about exactly?

Comment: sdcard read permissions.